# A good performance algorithm for node-link in this particular case

Tags: javascript, optimization, graph, datatables

I have a typical node-link graph
the node and the link are json object with structure like
node

```
id:
type:....
```

links

```
from: (nodeid)
to: (nodeid)
type:....
```

My current implementation requires when provided a nodeid, get out the immediate relationship and write it to table (the table using DataTable library)
I did the following:

```
  //Building array of links that are related to that nodeid
  function setSelectedNodeLinks(node, links) {
  self.selectedNodeLinks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
  if (node.id === links[i].nodeEndIdEntity ||node.id === links[i].nodeStartIdEntity)
  self.selectedNodeLinks.push(links[i]);
  }}
```

then

```
   function updateEntitiesTable(selectedId) {
   var table = $("#TableGraphEntities").DataTable();
   for (var i = 0; i < table.rows()[0].length; i++) {
   var update = table.row(i).data();
   update._entityRelation = "";
    for (var r = 0; r < self.selectedNodeLinks.length; r++) {
        if (table.row(i).data().entityId !== selectedId) {
        if (table.row(i).data().entityId === self.selectedNodeLinks[r].nodeStartIdEntity || table.row(i).data().entityId === self.selectedNodeLinks[r].nodeEndIdEntity) {
                            update._entityRelation = self.selectedNodeLinks[r].relationType[0];
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {

                        break;
                    }
                }
                //table.row(i).data(update);
            }
            console.log("Done building table");
        }
```

But the end result, when having 500 nodes, is very slow (3,4 seconds). How can I optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from all the optimization can be used, in my case, I was unknowningly used a lot of DOM accessing stuff in the loop. Just simple change

```
table.row(i).data()
```

to

```
update
```

would give good result. Guess I should not think about different algorithm yet when the actual code still a big mess